# RandomizedSearchCV takes longer time with fewer elements to search

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I am having a strange issue, i am using a RandomizedSearchCV to optimize my parameters.

```python
para_RS =     {"max_depth": randint(1,70),
               "max_features": ["log2", "sqrt"],
               "min_samples_leaf": randint(5, 50),
               "criterion": ["entropy","gini"],
               "class_weight":['balanced'],
               "max_leaf_nodes":randint(2,20)
              }
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

if i include all these parameters, the output comes in 2-3 mins, however if i remove all the parameters and keeping only the below parameter, its taking forever to run and i have to kill the notebook

```python
para_RS =     {
               "max_depth": randint(1,70)
              }
```

and also if i remove fewer its take long time to run(5-10 mins).
below is the code:

```python
if (randomsearch == True):
        tick = time.time()

        print("Random_Search_begin")
        rs= RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=dt, cv=5, param_distributions=para_RS,
                               n_jobs=4,n_iter =30, scoring="roc_auc",return_train_score=True)
        rs.fit(trainx_outer,trainy_outer)

        # other code irrelevant to the issue...

        print("Random_Search_end")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to random nature of the following:

```
"max_depth": randint(1,70)
"max_leaf_nodes":randint(2,20)
```

`randint(1, 70)` will return an integer between 1, 70. So during different runs, a different value of `max_depth` is generated.

So it may happen that during a certain run, the value generated is very high. The speed of `DecisionTreeClassifier` is impacted by the value of `max_depth` and it `max_leaf_nodes`. If these are very large, the time will be very large.

Also, I am not sure how you are able to run this code. Because RandomizedSearchCV takes a parameter grid of dictionary of iterables. But your code will generate a single int for "max_depth", "max_leaf_nodes" instead of an array or iterable. So it should throw an error. Which version of sklearn are you using? Or is the code you shown here different than actual?

Comment: thanks Vivek for the answer, however, I doubt that depth is the reason, as if i mention all parameters and only max depth with the same randint(1,70) i see huge difference in the time. Both gives almost same results on max depth (in between 18-20). I ran with both settings( with all parameters and with only max depth) around 30-40 times and everytime with all parameters finishes in 2-3 and max depth takes forever.

Comment: I am running sklearn version 0.19.1 and python 3.6.Also, the "n_iter" parameter is the one drives how many times this RandomSearchCV runs and everytime it runs it calls the parameter search space and get a number via the randint function.

Comment: @user6658936 `randint()` returns an int and not a distribution which `RandomizedSearchCV` can call again and again in each iter.

Comment: i understand randint() returns a number but "n_iter" parameter is the one drives how many times this RandomSearchCV. Everytime the RandomSearchCV gets called based on that parameter, it calls a number from randint for that parameter. I have verified that. If i just do n_iter = 10 and with above code, it will return randomly pick 10 values for the max depth. below is the output of the cv_results_

Comment: 'params': [{'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 6, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'max_leaf_nodes': 11, 'min_samples_leaf': 44}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': 3, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'max_leaf_nodes': 4, 'min_samples_leaf': 7}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': 4, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'max_leaf_nodes': 17, 'min_samples_leaf': 42},

Comment: {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': 8, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_leaf_nodes': 8, 'min_samples_leaf': 36}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 2, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'max_leaf_nodes': 10, 'min_samples_leaf': 49}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 1, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_leaf_nodes': 5, 'min_samples_leaf': 49}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 8, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_leaf_nodes': 13, 'min_samples_leaf': 7},

Comment: {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': 1, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_leaf_nodes': 12, 'min_samples_leaf': 44}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 4, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'max_leaf_nodes': 3, 'min_samples_leaf': 15}, {'class_weight': 'balanced', 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': 3, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_leaf_nodes': 10, 'min_samples_leaf': 28}],

Comment: @user6658936 Aah yes, my bad. You are using `scipy.stats.randint`, I was thinking it to be `numpy.random.randint`. Sorry for confusion. Now for the time part, can you please post the complete code for both scenarios when you say `"if i mention all parameters and only max depth with the same randint(1,70) i see huge difference in the time"`

Answer (score 1):

you can close this, as it seems the problem went away when i started using the random seed in both the classifier and RandomSearchCV. Thanks for all the help.